# How to multiply two 4x4 matrices, written as two 16-element arrays?

Tags: arrays, matrix, pseudocode, matrix-multiplication

I need to have a 4x4 matrix like this:

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

represented as an array like this:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16]
```

How do I multiply two such "matrices"? I've been struggling with how to make the work for a few days now. I'm thinking this would require three for loops? Maybe two? Would they go to 4 or 16? Some pseudocode would be greatly appreciated :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I did it!

result = A*B:

```
for(var k=0; k<=12; k+=4){
    for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
        for (var j=0, bCount=0; j<4; j++, bCount+=4){
            result[k+i] += A[k+j%4] * B[bCount+i%4];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just in case anybody else drops by and wonders, I've implemented this and it does work. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this works well although I'm not sure why the % 4 is there. Leaving those out would give the same result I think as i and j never get to 4.